# Are there any ways to easily optimize Rust in VSCode?

Tags: debugging, optimization, rust

I'm currently working on optimizing a big Rust project. I'm very new to Rust so I don't know much about how to optimize. I saw in a Cherno video that there was a tool in Visual Studio C++ to see CPU usage per line of code, and I am wondering if there is a similar thing for VSCode Rust.

Comment: This is off topic, but what you're looking for is caller a profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Chayim Friedman mentioned, this is called a profiler. The Rust Performance book has a non-exhaustive list of profilers that work with Rust, as you can see [here](https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/profiling.html). Cachegrind and Callgrind seem to be closest to what you wish to achieve